# componentwillreceiveprops not called on react-native and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Why my componentWillReceiveProps not running on my react-native, i using react-navigation and redux. i execute button login in reducer i using immutable. in store already update but componentWillReceiveProps not running just jump to componentWillUpdate and DidUpdate only

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Main extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     active : '',
     username: '',
     password: ''
  }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
 console.log(newProps.load(), 'Component WILL RECIEVE PROPS!')
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
 console.log(nextProps, nextState, 'Component WILL UPDATE!');
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 console.log(prevProps,'Component DID UPDATE!')
}

handleButtonAction(actions){
 let user = this.state.username
 let pass = this.state.password
 if(actions === 'login'){
   this.props.login(user, pass)
 }
}

render(){
  const {navigation} = this.props;
return(
          <Button block onPress={()=>this.handleButtonAction('login')} style=
   {{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10}}>
            <Text>Login</Text>
          </Button>
   )}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  token: state.token
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 login: (user, pass)=> dispatch({type:"LOGIN", payload:'testing'}),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main)
```

---

In Reducer i already using immutable but why at this update and still receiveProps on component not called

```
const listProduct = (oldstate, value)=>{
 console.log(oldstate);
 let newState = {...oldstate, data: value.data.data}
 console.log(newState);
 return newState
}

const login = (oldstate, value)=>{
 let newState = {...oldstate, token: value}
 return newState
}

const initialState = {}

const product = (state=initialState, actions)=>{
 switch (actions.type) {
 case "GET_PRODUCK": return listProduct(state, actions.payload);
 case "LOGIN": return login(state, actions.payload);
 default: return state
}}

export default product
```

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps will only call when the props have changed and when this is not an initial rendering.

componentWillReceiveProps will not be called if you are receiving the exact same props as before.

We triggered it from update new values in state.

So in Here, you need to dispatch the function `login`

`this.props.login(user, pass)` this will not call your reducer function

Syntext of dispatch is like `this.props.dispatch(xyz.login(user, pass)}` then it will called reducer function login and update state